# If God was not created, and He is eternal, the why was His form - i.e. the Holy Spirit and His Son, perfectly suited to salvation?

Tags: trinity, tradition, persons-of-the-trinity, non-trinitarian

The Son only has to exist if Man needed to saved, He is not inherent by any means. Likewise, a similar argument can be made for the Holy Ghost. How, then, can all three Persons of the Trinity be uncreated, inherent in God's nature, yet work out perfectly in order for His plan of grace? I am looking for a trinitarian, Bible-based answer, although Catholic tradition or papal statements may be included as way of explanation.

Comment: "The Son only has to exist if Man needed to saved" Why do you think this is the case?? A strong argument for a multi-personal God is that God couldn't be inherently and eternally loving if he was unipersonal.

Comment: I have read this argument, yes - but why, then, a Son? Why a Holy Spirit? Why not just 2 equals? Furthermore, why would a God have to be loving at all?

Comment: This is getting into a very speculative area of theology. People do have various ideas, but they're not definitive. But I'd suggest for now that you focus on improving your question by justifying the claims you're making.

Comment: This seems to me to be personal opinion and does not equate to any systematic theology that I recognise. It is completely contrary to Trinitarian doctrine as set out at Nicaea and as further developed over the centuries. It appears to me to be wholly eccentric and personal to the OP (unless the OP can show some research and some cited references to the contrary).

Comment: IF Man needed to be saved? And have you never read that Father, Son and Holy Spirit are co-eternal and co-equal?  I'm afraid I don't understand your question since you have not provided any sources that might explain your thinking.  As it stands, your question is likely to attract opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is neither a shallow nor a quickly explained aspect of the nature of God so I'll keep it short; questions and pushback will abound either way.

The Son is Logos (John 1:1), which is to say not just the spoken word and not just the concept behind the word but including the rational mind which conceives the concept.  To suppose God without the Son (Logos) is to suppose God without a rational mind.

This same God has perfect, infinite integrity such that there is no ontological difference between who He is (Father), what He says (Son/Logos), and what/how He does (Spirit).  If the Father has personhood then so does the Son and so also the Spirit.  Not modalism (as in 3 different parts of one God) but Trinity (as in one God revealed in three persons).

Prior to and irregardless of the creation of man He is God:  Father, Son, and Spirit.

Answer (score 2):

The Bible is clear that God was not created, that he is without beginning and without end, therefore - eternal. There is no "if" about that, as your comment clarifies.

The question is asking about God's "form", how it is perfectly suited to salvation. But (problematically) the Bible states that God is Spirit, and nobody has ever seen his form. Yet the uncreated, eternal Holy Spirit has been seen at a particular time as the dove at Jesus' baptism, while the *logos* manifested at one particular time, at the incarnation, as the uncreated, eternal Son of God.

The *logos* (Word of God) incarnated at one particular time as Jesus Christ. But God is Spirit and nobody can see his form and live, yet people have seen Jesus Christ on Earth, and lived. This provides the answer to the main question, for the *logos* became flesh at a particular point in time, in order to die to save sinners. The Father sent the Son, who agreed to come, and the Holy Spirit was the agent involved in all of that.
All three persons of the Trinity were involved in this miracle of salvation.

It was not "God's form" that was "perfectly suited to salvation" (as the question supposes) for God Spirit is. The Holy Spirit is likewise Spirit. But the *logos*, the Word of God, could and did become perfectly suited to salvation. He

> "made himself of no reputation, and took upon him the form of a
> servant, and was made in the likeness of men: and being found in
> fashion as a man, he humbled himself, and became obedient unto death,
> even the death of the cross." Philippians 2:6-8 A.V.

The Father and the Holy Spirit continued (as they were, so to speak) communicating with the *logos* who was now made flesh as the man, Jesus, enabling the perfect will of the Father in heaven to be carried out through the willing Son on Earth. All three persons of the Holy Trinity were involved in working out the plan of salvation. The *logos*, made flesh, could not have become flesh without the Holy Spirit and the Father working together from the incarnation through to the resurrected Christ ascending back to share the throne of God in heaven.

The trinitarian answer is that all three Persons of the Trinity were equally involved in creation as they were in executing the plan of salvation for fallen creation to be restored. All mainstream Christianity - Catholic, Orthodox and Protestant - are agreed on this.

Comment: The "if" is not asking, it is prefacing an assumption - it could easily be replaced with 'since' .